# Use a callback to toggle the collapse on small screens

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I saw a lot of this in many code examples and I also even use this code by copying it from somewhere. But I don't understand what they do. Can anyone help me with the below code?

```py
# we use a callback to toggle the collapse on small screens
@app.callback(
    Output("navbar-collapse", "is_open"),
    [Input("navbar-toggler", "n_clicks")],
    [State("navbar-collapse", "is_open")],
)
def toggle_navbar_collapse(n, is_open):
    if n:
        return not is_open
    return is_open


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This callback is triggered by clicking on clickable element (mostly likely a button) with id `navbar-toggler`. This is an `input` argument meaning whenever the `n_click` changes for this element, the callback is triggered.

The `state` argument is the collapsible element's current collapsed state (either `True` or `False`).

The `if` condition checks whether the button has been clicked on yet, if not then it is most likely the initial loading of the app, and so just return the the current collapsible element's collapsed state as it is. If the `n_clicks` is greater than 0 (ie. the callback was triggered by the click), then return the negation of the current collapsible element's collapsed state (ie. if it is `True` change to `False` and vice versa). This way, when it is collapsed and you toggle the button, the collapsible element will re-open and vice versa.